# Lovász theta function of vertex disjoint union

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Let $\theta(G+H)$ denote the Lovász theta function of the vertex disjoint union of graphs $G$ and $H$. Prove that $\theta(G+H)\leq \theta(G) + \theta(H)$.

I believe that the stronger claim that $\theta(G+H)= \theta(G) + \theta(H)$ is also true as proven by Donald Knuth in section 18 of "[the sandwich theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9312214)".

However, I was wondering if there is a simpler way of showing that the weaker inequality above holds.

Comment: I think skipping some reasoning in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71561 suffices

Comment: @VezenBU I just took a look through, but I am confused about the final step. How does the final result imply the equality?

Comment: You may see that by drawing a plot